# How do I efficiently get the property as a list from IReadOnlyCollection?

Tags: c#

I have a IReadOnlyCollection of a class called `MyProducts` looking like this:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 2987,
        "Name": Brick,

        ...
    },
    {
        "Id": 35246,
        "Name": Wood,

        ...
    },

...

]
```

How can I efficiently get the IDs as a list like this:

```
[
    "2987",
    "35246"
]
```

I would prefer not to use a loop. Is there for example an inbuilt function that can help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use LINQ:

```
List<int> idList = products.Select(p => p.Id).ToList();
```

That's not more efficient than a plain loop but it's shorter, so probably more readable.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Tim's answer with a non-LINQ solution:

```
List<int> ids = new List<int>(products.Count);
for(int i = 0; i < products.Count; ++i)
    ids.Add(products[i].Id);
```